# I am not able to use Python colorgram in VS Code. It showing the error while extracting the colors from the image

Tags: python

I usually code on Visual-studio-code.But now I tried to use colorgram module in it and I am getting an error while extracting the colors from my image.As this module is mainly used for extracting colors from any image.

THIS IS MY CODE :

```py
# list of colors from the image 
 rgb_colors = [] 
  
 # extracting the colors from the image 
 colors = colorgram.extract("hirst_image.jpg", 30) 
  
 # appending each image color to the "rgb_colors" list 
 for color in colors: 
     # These lines will helps in understanding the code above inside the for loop 
     # rgb_colors.append(color) 
     # print(rgb_colors) 
     r = color.rgb.r 
     g = color.rgb.g 
     b = color.rgb.b 
     new_color = (r, g, b) 
     rgb_colors.append(new_color) 
  
 # printing the "rgb_colors" list 
 print(rgb_colors)
```

Iam expecting a list of tuples which contains the rgb color values extracted from my image.

Comment: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Comment: Without more information about the error message you are seeing, it's difficult to provide a specific solution.